# when does fb app is required

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Can you any one help me with basic question when is facebook app is required.
If we use just recommend Or Facebook Comments or Facebook like ,is facebook app requried?

Comment: It's required if you want to use Facebook.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I mean if i only wanted to use facebook like button than is it required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A full app is not required to use the Like button or the Comments plugin.  You can find more information about them here:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/